# xlslib build success in iOS 7 but failed in iOS 8. How can I do?

Tags: ios, xlslib

I have searched  http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/files here and download the library. I added the library into my xcode project like this

[image]

My xcode version is 6.4 and my project iOS Deployment Target is 8.0.

After I added it into the project without typing any code, I just built to see if it works.

But I failed and get these information:
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '(MyProject Directory)/xlslib/libxls.3.dylib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I changed iOS Deployment Target to 7.0, build the project by using iOS simulator with iOS version 7.1, it works. Is the library doesn't support iOS 8.0 and later ?

BTW, other link flag is already be empty, what should I do to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.